# Error in git trying clone a repo with a dot at the end

Tags: git, github

$ git clone https://github.com/LautaroMoreira01/tps_laboratorio_ii..git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'tps_laboratorio_ii.': Invalid argument

when I try to clone that repository or another with a period at the end of the path, I get an error that does not occur with any other repository.
I tried clone from bash or gui and github desktop.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRcbE.png)

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/317 this looks like a windows issue?

Comment: Dots in Windows can be special. You're probably better off renaming the repository to remove the dot.

Comment: i read the issue and yes maybe i must change the repo name. thaks!

Answer (score 1):

Eithe rename the repository or clone to a different directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/LautaroMoreira01/tps_laboratorio_ii..git tps_laboratorio_ii # <- No dot at the end
```